# How to upgrade R in linux Mint?

Tags: r, linux, upgrade, linux-mint

I am using Linux mint 18.3. I have installed R. My current R version is 3.4.4 But I want to upgrade it to version 3.5.

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Add an R apt-repository

https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu-12-04/

It's for an older version, but the process is the same across versions